# Errors upgrading from eclipse-update-site to eclipse-repository Maven packaging

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am using Tycho and Maven to build an eclipse update site containing several plugins. Everything worked happily when I packaged it as an **eclipse-update-site**, but I'm getting errors now that I've switched to **eclipse-repository**.

My projects looks like

```
com.mycompany.plugin/
  src/things.java
  pom.xml

com.mycompany.plugin.feature/
  feature.xml
  pom.xml

com.mycompany.updatesite/
  category.xml (formerly site.xml)
  pom.xml
```

[This page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types) indicates that the maven packaging "eclipse-update-site" is deprecated in favor of "eclipse-repository". Accordingly, I updated my update site's pom.xml to look like (approximately):

```
<project>
  <tycho.version>0.26.0</tycho.version>
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
         <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${tycho.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
</project>
```

I also renamed my site.xml file to category.xml as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945466/eclipse-p2-difference-between-category-xml-and-site-xml) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124702/tycho-p2-repository-plugin-fails-with-no-content-specified-for-p2-repository). I did not make any other changes to category.xml (formerly site.xml), so it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/com.mycompany.plugin.feature_0.1.0.qualifier.jar" id="com.mycompany.plugin.feature" version="0.1.0.qualifier">
      <category name="com.mycompany"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="com.mycompany" label="MyPlugin"/>
</site>
```

The maven build marches along happily, building all of my plugins and features. When it tries to build the repository, it fails, saying:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.26.0:assemble-repository
(default-assemble-repository) on project com.mycompany.updatesite: Could not assemble p2 repository:
Mirroring failed: No repository found at file:/mypath/com.mycompany.updatesite/target/. -> [Help 1]
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Which phases of maven are you running?

I encountered the same problem when switching from `eclipse-update-site` to `eclipse-repository` and using just the `package` phase. However, it worked with `install`.

Or more specifically instead of

```
mvn clean package
```

I used

```
mvn clean install
```

I hope this helps you too.